# About Powershell register-objectevent action

Tags: powershell

Are powershell register-objectevent action blocks executed sequentially?

For exaample:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $someObject -EventName SomeEvent -Action { 
Write-Host  "start process"; 
#some time taking process;
Write-Host "end process";
}
```

If there are several events of "SomeEvent" fired together. Will the action block get executed sequentially or or in parallel? If it is parallel how to make it sequential?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They execute sequentially and only at times when the PowerShell engine deems it safe.  At those times, PowerShell will look at the event queue, dequeue an event and execute its Action scriptblock.  IIRC, PowerShell checks in between iterations of loops and maybe between stages of a pipeline.  The bottom line is that as the events occur async, on whatever thread the event fires on, the only thing PowerShell does in immediate response is to queue the event.  Later on, PowerShell will drain the events off the queue and execute them in a way that won't cause threading issues with the currently executing pipeline.

Comment: Is there anywhere I could read about this in more detail? It's interesting to me how much differently Register-ObjectEvent behaves when you provide it an Action and I'd like to understand it a bit better. This answer is literally one of two places I've found that provides even a little bit of clarity about how this works (the other being http://bit.ly/1A0AQnf, under "Asynchronous Processing of Events").